# SQL (BigQuery): How do i use a single value, derived with another query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my query:

```
WITH last_transaction AS (
  SELECT
    month
  FROM db.transactions
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM db.transactions
-- WHERE month = last_transaction.month
WHERE month = 11
GROUP BY
  id
```

Commented out line doesn't work, but intention is clear, i assume: i need to select transactions for the latest month. Business logic might not make sense, because i've extracted it from a bigger query. The main question is: how do i use a single value, derived with another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one row, so you can use a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM db.transactions t
WHERE month = (SELECT last_transaction.month FROM last_transaction);
```

I removed the `GROUP BY id` because it would be a syntax error in BigQuery and it logically does not make sense.  Why would a column called `id` be duplicated in the table?

However, this query would often be written as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, MAX(month) OVER () as max_month
      FROM db.transactions t
WHERE month = max_month;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to JOIN the last_transaction.

A bit like this;

```
SELECT *
FROM db.transactions
JOIN last_transaction
ON db.transactions.id = last_transaction.id
WHERE month = last_transaction.month
GROUP BY id
```